# How should we handle failed credit card payments?

Tags: stripe-payments, saas, recurring-billing

We're just a few weeks away from releasing our custom built SaaS app for Freight Brokers and (eventually) Carriers. We're deciding how to handle failed credit card payments. The options have so far been:

1. Immediately restrict their account and require a payment. Send them an email saying an Admin can login and restore account access

or

2. Give them 7 full days to pay(including weekends), send them an email when the payment fails, a day after and 2 days after the second email. Then send them an email when their account access has been restricted. When they login, they can pay, but the payment would include the days used without payment.

I'm leaning towards the second one, because if I were a business owner, i would not want to come in and my employees are sitting because none of them have a company credit card to pay for the software.

Thoughts?

EDIT: Lmao I spelt "handle" wrong in the title... Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure [Stripe Dunning](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/automatic-collection) process which facilitates you to handle failed payments in a better way for subscription base billing.

Its basically enabling `retry schedule` with `customize timeframe`. you can `cancel` the subscription or mark the subscription as `unpaid` after all retry attempts have been exhausted. There is a `webhook` which indicates the transaction details, using that you can handle your business logic like `hold` the tenant or `delete` the tenant.

Comment: So I know how to develop it, but this is more of a business question lol. How much time do you give an end user(company) to pay before you get rid of their access.